# Django stuck urls.py

Tags: python, linux, django, apache, debian

I've a django application long time ago, and I tried to update it today. On the test server everything went fine, but in production I got some error. After digging, I found that apache2 loads always the old version of the urls.py, and this is the reason of my problem. I deleted all the .pyc files, restarted apache2, but nothing has changed. I got the same behaviour if I put syntax error into the urls.py files, or if I delete them. Like I'd edit a wrong file, but I don' t.

Any idea what else could I do? I already migrated back to the old version in production, but still, if I edit the urls.py files, it has no effect.

Details:

debian version: 6.0.2
python version: 2.6.6
django version: 1.4.5-1~bpo60+2
apache2 version: 2.2.16-6+squeeze1

Comment: it's impossible to say with limited details of your setup but I would imagine somehow, someway you're editing the wrong urls.py file.

Comment: Well, i really would like to think that i' m editing the wrong file. I colledted all the urls.py files on the server, and went through carefully, but only one has this settings. Most probably it' s my fault, however i can' t find out what i do wrongly. What other informations would You need?

Comment: I have myself run into this kind of problems many times, basically due to my own negligence, no offence meant.
But, if you do a `find . -type f urls.py` in your django directory, you might find that there is a duplicate in some path. Please provide more details for the answer to be more specific

Comment: Godman: yes, i just found a recursive duplicate in the root directory of the application before i read your comment. Huh, strange. I don' t really understand why it tries to fetches the information from there, but probably it has a logical reason.